# Connecting to FTP Server from behind HTTP Proxy

Tags: java, proxy, ftp

I am trying to connect to FTP Server using **ftp4j** library.

```
it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient ftpClient = new it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient();
ftpClient.setConnector(new
        it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.connectors.HTTPTunnelConnector("myproxy.com", 8080));

ftpClient.connect("ftp.myserver.com");
```

I am getting following exception:

> java.io.IOException: FTPConnection closed
>       at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPCommunicationChannel.read(FTPCommunicationChannel.java:144)
>       at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPCommunicationChannel.readFTPReply(FTPCommunicationChannel.java:187)
>       at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.connect(FTPClient.java:1041)
>       at com.ge.supplierenrichment.core.SupplierEnrichment.main(SupplierEnrichment.java:113)

Can someone tell me an approach to connect to ftp from behind proxy.

I have tried apache's commons net as well. However, I am able to connect using `URLConnection`.

Thanks

Comment: Does your HTTP proxy also act as an FTP proxy?

Comment: I need to tunnel over HTTP